# Sorting jobs by date posted results in incorrect order when filtering by location

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, sorting

To reproduce:

- Enter a location filter (e.g. "London")
- Sort by date posted

Currently the results look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks, this should be resolved. Would you try it again?